# meaning of the phrasal verb "imagine away"

Tags: meaning

Here is the context it was used in: "If we close our eyes in a silent room, the feeling of having a body is not something we can imagine away." Does "imagine away mean to imagine something instantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preposition *away* here has the sense *at a distance* or *removed* from the current physical or figurative context, as when we send something *away* or tell children to put their toys *away*.

In the construction *VERB X away*, *VERB* acts as a causative and the preposition acts as a secondary predicate on its object *X*: that is, one causes *X* to be 'away', out of sight or out of mind, by *VERBing*.

Your sentence, then, may be paraphrased:

> . . .the feeling of having a body is not something we can dismiss from consciousness by a mere act of imagination.